# Home HDD Storage - Internal (SATA) vs. External (Gigabit)

Tags: hard-drive, raid, sata, gigabit-ethernet

I've been considering setting up a fileserver for my home storage.

Would an external HDD setup at Gigabit speeds be slower then just staying with internally installed, SATA III-speed drives in my desktop? Or is the bottleneck going to be the speeds of the drives themselves? (For the purposes of this question, assume 7,200 RPM drives)

I have never used a RAID setup; would that theoretically make a difference?

Comment: When you say gigabit, I assume you are meaning that it is network attached. Is that correct? In terms of bus, Sata3 runs at 6 Gibabit/second, so about 600MB/s for raw transfer speed. SATA2 runs at 3 Gb/s. Either way, these busses far exceed gigabit network speed. That said of course, most disks cannot make use of full SATA3 speeds, so the type of disk will have an impact on the ultimate throughput. RAID can both speed up and slow down differant operations at each of the RAID levels. which raid are you thinking about?

Comment: Yes, the idea is a networked server or perhaps standalone NAS. That's what I was thinking; I'll hit the HDD bottleneck before Gigabit's slower bus speed becomes an issue. If I do RAID then based on my research so far, probably level 6 or 10.